# No BD - что это за система организации данных

Tags: nosql

Господа, посвятите

Все чаще сталкиваюсь с словесным выражением No BD, когда речь идет про хранение информации в больших объемах. На тех кто использует реляционные БД смотрят как на динозавров

Есть базы SQL/MySQL/MsSQL и прочие, некоторые хранят данные в XML/JSON файлах. А No BD - это что за система организации данных?

p.s. если есть статья на эту тему поучительная - буду очень признателен

Comment: Вы с NoSQL не перепутали часом?

Comment: MySQL,MsSQL это даже не бд, это субд, посмотрите сначала википедию по всему что вы написали.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No BD** - нет такого понятия, потому что хотя бы NO DB должно быть и вероятно это можно представить как хранение данных без базы данных.

Вы перепутали значения, есть такое понятия как **NoSQL**, которое часто переводят как "нет sql", это неправильно! Правильный перевод "не только sql"

Я не буду описывать плюсы и минусы конкретной технологии, этих статей много при первой ссылке в поисковой системе: NoSQL vs SQL

Хочется сказать, что в современном мире нет противостояния между реляционными и нереляционными базами данных. Вместо этого стоит говорить об их совместном использовании для решения задач, на которых та или иная технология показывает себя лучше всего. Где-то требуется консистентность и высокая согласованность данных в жестких ограничениях, где это нужно быстрое чтение и запись со структурой которую всегда можно быстро изменить.